# why doesn't watch work when piping the output of fortune into cowsay

Tags: linux, watch, piping

cowsay is a silly linux tool for displaying a cow saying given text in the terminal.

```
$ cowsay hello
```

fortune is a silly linux too for displaying a "random" quote in the terminal.

```
$ fortune
```

Both of these commands can be repeatedly ran in the terminal using watch e.g.

```
$ watch cowsay hello
$ watch fortune
```

Additionally these two commands can be combined so the cow says "random" quotes. By piping the output of fortune into cowsay.

```
$ fortune | cowsay
```

However a combination of the use of watch and piping the output of fortune into cowsay doesn't do anything.... i.e. hangs until the process is ended

```
$ watch fortune | cowsay
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `watch fortune | cowsay` you are piping the output of `watch fortune` into `cowsay`.  You want to `watch` the value of `fortune` piped to `cowsay` so you should quote it so watch will get the whole command to execute as

```
watch 'fortune | cowsay'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because everything after `|` is executed in a subshell. Try this:

```
$ watch "fortune | cowsay"
```